# Invalid device pointer error

Tags: cuda

I have the following sample code.

```
struct Data
{
float* arr_f_ptr;
int* arr_i_ptr;
short* arr_s_ptr;

size_t arr_f_size;
size_t arr_f_size_bytes;
size_t arr_i_size;
size_t arr_i_size_bytes;
size_t arr_s_size;
size_t arr_s_size_bytes);
};


void processing (Data &d)
{

// call some kernels on d.arr_f_ptr, d.arr_i_ptr, d.arr_s_ptr

// using cufftExecR2C on d.arr_f_ptr, d.arr_i_ptr, d.arr_s_ptr

}

Data d;

// filling the sizes of the arrays
d.arr_f_size = ....;
d.arr_f_size_bytes = d.arr_f_size * sizeof(float);
d.arr_i_size = ....;
d.arr_i_size_bytes = d.arr_i_size * sizeof(int);
d.arr_s_size = ....;
d.arr_s_size_bytes = d.arr_s_size * sizeof(short);

size_t total_size_bytes = arr_f_size_bytes + arr_i_size_bytes + arr_s_size_bytes;

// allocate device memory
char *device_pointer;
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&device_pointer, total_size_bytes));

// map memory to pointers
size_t index = 0;
d.arr_f_ptr = (float*)&device_pointer[index];   index += d.arr_f_size_bytes;
d.arr_i_ptr = (int*)&device_pointer[index];     index += d.arr_i_size_bytes;
d.arr_s_ptr = (short*)&device_pointer[index];

// copy data from host to arrays in data
....
// call processing function
processing(d);
// deallocate
....
```

Where I try to allocate linear array in the device memory, then map three different arrays (of different types) to contiguous location on this linear array.
The thing is that when the kernel is called in the processing function, I get unspecified launch failure error. also when I use cufftExecR2C on this data I get invalid device memory pointer error.

Inside the processing function, I copied back the input data (in d) from the host, and checked it. It seems exactly correct and matching the data in the host. So, I know that the copy to the host is done correctly, and the device memory contains the correct data.

So, what is the reason for such error I got here??
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's alignment issue, you could use 3 `cudaMalloc` to allocate the space for each array separately.

> Any address of a variable residing in global memory or returned by one
>   of the memory allocation routines from the driver or runtime API is
>   always aligned to at least 256 bytes.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and sorry for the late response from me. I tried to be sure that the memory is aligned for 256 bytes, but still gives me invalid device memory. Do you have any link for code that allocates big memory, and map it to several arrays?

Comment: If the memory is big, why can't you use 3 separate malloc? You may want to try this way at least to ensure  it's not a problem other than misalignment.   I seldom see people use it in your way.

Comment: Thanks Eric for the prompt response. Actually, the code above is just sample code. I need to create tens for arrays. Performance wise, I found that allocating one big array and manage this memory, and map it for several array is faster than allocating many times. This is the reason that I need to allocate using only one cudaMalloc.

Comment: Maybe you mis-calculate the alignment. Maybe at this time, correctness first. Maybe you still get error with separate malloc.

Comment: I had a version with separate malloc, and it works fine. The error I got when I use one big malloc. For alignment, for each array I use a size of memory which is multiple of 256, I guess this way all arrays should be aligned, aren't they?

Comment: So, in the above code, index should be incremented always with a value which is multiple of 256 bytes. Isn't this the correct way?

Comment: Yes and you need a larger total_size_bytes

Answer (score 1):

You forgot alignment.It can be byte, word, dword and so on.

So, the size of Data can change according it.

sizeof(Data) may be not the sum of sizeof(each member)

Check by code that 
(arr_f_size_bytes + arr_i_size_bytes + arr_s_size_bytes == sizeof(Data))
If it is false, you have missalignment.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `sizeof(Data)`.